# R How to Search for String Pattern and Extract Custom character lengths from that location?

Tags: r, regex

I am looking to extract a pattern and then a custom number of characters to the left or right of that pattern. I believe this is possible with Regex but unsure how to proceed. Below is an example of the data and the output I am looking for:

```
library(data.table)
#my data set
df = data.table(
  event = c(1,2,3),
  notes = c("watch this movie from 4-7pm",
            "watch this musical from 5-9pm",
            "eat breakfast at this place from 7-9am")

)

#how do I point R to a string section and then pull characters around it?

#example:
grepl('pm|am',df$notes) # I can see an index that these keywords exist but how can I tell R
#locate that word and then maybe pull N digits to the left, or n digits to right like substr()

#output would be 
#'4-7pm', '5-9pm', '7-9am'

#right now I can extract the pattern:
library(stringr)
str_extract(df$notes, "pm")
#but I also want to then pull things to the left or right of it.
```

Comment: Try `str_extract(df$notes, "\\d+-\\d+(?=[ap]m)")` if you just want the numeric ranges.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `stringr` you could do something like this. With the matrix of locations you could tinker with moving around the radius for whatever you are looking for:

```
library(stringr)

# Extacting locations
locations <- str_locate(df$notes, "\\d+\\-\\d+pm|\\d+\\-\\d+am")

# Using substring to pull the info you want
str_sub(df$notes, locations)

[1] "12-7pm" "5-9pm"  "7-9am"
```

Data (I swapped out 4 for 12):

```
df = data.table(
  event = c(1,2,3),
  notes = c("watch this movie from 12-7pm",
            "watch this musical from 5-9pm",
            "eat breakfast at this place from 7-9am")

)
```

Comment: this is great, thanks, similar to Sonny's at the bottom. I gave him an upvote but will give you the answer since you set it all up. Appreciate the help!

Comment: Very similar thinking! Only thing this adds us the use of `str_sub` after. I'll leave it up for that reason.

Answer (score 2):

May in your case, just the below should work:

```
sapply(df$notes, function(x) {
  grep("am|pm", unlist(strsplit(x, " ")), value = T)
}, USE.NAMES = FALSE)
[1] "4-7pm" "5-9pm" "7-9am"
```

However, this can still fail because of edge cases.
You can also try regex to extract all works ending with am or pm

Look at `stringr` to locate the extract characters and build the radius:

```
 stringr::str_locate(df$notes, "am|pm")
     start end
[1,]    26  27
[2,]    28  29
[3,]    37  38
```

Comment: Thanks, this could definitely work, but yeah I am more curious in having the ability to build a radius around the pattern because then I can extract a given radius around lets say the '-' and clean out what I extract to leave only numbers and an am or pm.

Comment: You can use str_locate to get the location of the matching characters and build the radius: `stringr::str_locate(df$notes, "am|pm")
     start end
[1,]    26  27
[2,]    28  29
[3,]    37  38`